# Clarification on sqlplus command

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I do a bulk insert.Is the below command correct??

```
sqlplus -U user_tr -P metro -S TUS234 -D TransportDB  -SILENT -INPUTFILE rollout.txt -OUTPUTFILE sql.out
```

The input file cotains a bulk of insert statements.I want to execute those and the result must be in the output file.This was my attempt.

So far everything went well in the script,but I am unable to open the o/p file.

> Error opening the o/p file

Is the command problem where the specification is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recognise the syntax you are using - see [the SQL Plus docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch3.htm#i1168761).  As far as I know there are no command line flags like -U, -P, -INPUT, -OUTPUT in SQL Plus.

You can start SQL Plus and run a script from the command line like this:

```
sqlplus -silent myusername/mypassword@mydatabase @myscript.txt
```

I think the syntax to write all output to a file is OS-dependent, but something like:

```
sqlplus -silent myusername/mypassword@mydatabase @myscript.txt > output.txt
```

Alternatively, you can add SQL Plus SPOOL commands inside the script.